# Copying a file from local folder to "C:\Windows\System32\" using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I am writing an application which uses batch file to copy some files to another location. I am using 64-bit windows 7.

I have asked for admin privileges too using below code:

**Code block to get ADMIN right**:

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code starts)
REM --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) 
else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code ends)
:: Your codes should start from the following line
```

**Code to copy a file to system32 folder**:

```
copy /d /Y "D:\opt\optPath.txt" "C:\Windows\System32\"
```

There is no error in copy operation, but the file is copied to "**C:\Windows\SysWOW64**" location automatically. Need help.

Comment: You are running the  `copy` command with the 32bit command interpreter, and due to [WoW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) it ends up in the current location. How are you starting it?

Comment: You are using a 32 bit program - that is the 32 bit System32 directory. `C:\Windows\SysNative` allows 32 bit programs to access the 64 bit system32. Windows uses 64 bit programs unless you do something. Putting `cmd /c copy /d /y "D:\opt\optPath.txt" "C:\Windows\SysNative\*.*"` into a shortcut then setting it to Run As Admin (right click - Properties - Shortcut tab - Advanced button and tick Run As Admin. Or copy the file in vbscript `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFile "D:\opt\optPath.txt", "C:\Windows\SysNative\optPath.txt", True`

Comment: @Alex. Batch files are already 64 bit unless you are doing something weird.

Comment: @alex no it doesn't - it launches the same bitness. As VBScript will be 64 bit unless someone overrides it. There is a configuration problem

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
@echo off
:: Batch-Admin API
    net file>nul 2>&1&&if "%~1"=="64" (goto:GotAdmin) else (if exist "%windir%\Sysnative\" (call start %windir%\Sysnative\cmd /c "%~0" 64&exit) else (goto:GotAdmin))
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    (echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
     echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "ELEV","", "runas", 0 ) > "%temp%\admin.vbs"
    cscript /Nologo "%temp%\admin.vbs"&exit

:GotAdmin
:: Place ADMIN tasks below
    copy /d /Y "D:\opt\optPath.txt" "C:\Windows\System32\"
    pause
exit
```

I <del>modified</del> rewrote your script to:

- **Use an alternative way to check for admin permissions** `net file && echo Admin || echo No-admin`
- **Added 64-bit launcher** `VBScript` launches everything as `32-bit` (redirecting `C:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`).

*64-Bit launcher:
`call start %WinDir%\SysNative\cmd /c %0`* (This window is hidden)